# JUnit: test if ID of type int is null when creating JavaBean

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot

I am a bit new to testing. I have a small app with spring boot and oracle db. I want to write a test when my JavaBean class can have empty ID int value. Is this even possible to test?

Currently I have this code, but I do not think it works correct.

```
ReportModel reportModel = new ReportModel();

Validator validator = createValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<ReportModel>> constraintViolationSet = validator.validate(reportModel);

assertThat(constraintViolationSet.size()).isEqualTo(0);
```

**Edited**: full test class:

```
public class ValidatorTests {

    private Validator createValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotValidateWhenIdIsNull() {
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ReportModel reportModel = new ReportModel();

        Validator validator = createValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<ReportModel>> constraintViolationSet = validator.validate(reportModel);

        assertThat(constraintViolationSet.size()).isEqualTo(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a little more context? And more code of test? Testing of beans connected with a proper path to context files and runners. And add more details what is not working now? Is it a problem with checking that bean has empty id? Or you can not even run test?

Comment: What was not working: test was failing. Below answer solved that problem.

Comment: Great, then mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
assertEquals(constraintViolationSet.size(), 0);
```

or,

```
assertTrue(constraintViolationSet.isEmpty());
```

Comment: If this fixes anything, then your problem lies somewhere else, since this "solution" just replaces your AssertJ assertion with a Hamcrest one that does basically just the same thing. You could write the same thing with AssertJ as `assertThat(constraintViolationSet).isEmpty()` - without risking a NullPointer. But this does not explain where your orignal problem was.

Comment: my original problem was that my tests didn't pass. Now they pass, but I am not sure it is correct to test an entity bean for parameter being empty. But this is another question already.